# Call Module function from Controller (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, module, controller

So I have a module "MiddleMan"   I am able to call it just fine in the rails console but in the controller I am getting a NoMethodError

In the controller I have:

```
class SignUpController < ApplicationController
  include MiddleMan
  def page_one
      @package = MiddleMan::read_catalog("a", "b", "c")
  end
end
```

And in the middleman.rb  module I have:

```
module MiddleMan
  def read_catalog(package, payment, coupon)
    Package.new(:price => "4.99")
  end
end
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you included the module the instance method `read_catalog` is added to your Class, so you can call it directly:

```
class SignUpController < ApplicationController
  include MiddleMan
  def page_one
      @package = read_catalog("a", "b", "c")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks this worked... I also had to change my name of the middleman file to middle_man.rb

Comment: As a side note, if you want to call methods from a module directly, without mixing them in, you need to define them as `def self.method_name` so that they are bound to the module instance itself.  Another (odd) trick here is to make the module extend itself.  You don't use the `::` syntax though, you just use a dot.