# LoadError - Expected to define. Rails error when calling module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module

I have a module called EntityTrackerHelper. Here is the code:

```
module EntityTrackerHelper
    def self.createUserAction(user_id, type, entity_id)
        existingua = UserAction.find(:first, :conditions=> ["user_id = ? and type = ? and entity_id=?", user_id, type, entity_id])
        if existingua.nil?
            ua = UserAction.new
            ua.user_id = user_id
            ua.type = type
            ua.entity_id = entity_id
            ua.date = Time.now
            ua.save
        else
            existingua.date = Time.now
            existingua.save
        end
    end
end
```

It is used to track changes and user access in an entity.
It is used in a controller as follows.

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/EntityTrackerHelper"
class LessonSectionsController < InheritedResources::Base
    def index
      user_id = params[:user_id]
      lesson_id = params[:lesson_id]
      EntityTrackerHelper::createUserAction(user_id, 'LESSON', lesson_id)
      lessonSections = LessonSection.find(:all, :conditions => { :lesson_id => params[:lesson_id] })
      render :json => {:sections => lessonSections.as_json({:only => [:lesson_id,:id,:name]}), :error => ''}
    end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
LoadError (Expected /<ProjPath>/<ProjName>/app/models/lesson.rb to define LESSON):
  lib/EntityTrackerHelper.rb:12:in `createUserAction'
  app/controllers/lesson_sections_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

Line 12 in `EntityTrackerHelper` is `UserAction.find...`

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the model's code would be useful.

Comment: Which one? I don;t know why the error is in lesson.rb and the model that is involved is LessonSection (not Lesson)

Comment: The error talks about `app/models/lesson.rb`. Anyway, see my answer, I guess that's the reason why it is searching for `LESSON` in this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord will use the field `type` for "single table inheritance". See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html (subtitle: single table inheritance).

It means that when it loads the `UserAction` with type `LESSON`, ActiveRecord will try to instantiate the class `LESSON` which is not defined.

You probably should use another name for your `type` column.

Comment: THANK YOU! That was the problem. I will never user a column named type anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using

```
**include EntityTrackerHelper**
```

for more info  check this link [Call Module function from Controller (NoMethodError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604272/call-module-function-from-controller-nomethoderror)