# Converting an array of data-objects to raw data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts, ransack

This is probably a huge oversight on my part, but I have been searching for a fix for about an hour now, with no luck!

I am following the [RailsCast tutorial on exporting data to .CSV](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true)

The data I am using to populate the CSV is coming from a [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) query (in the params)

However, the data that is being spit out is a collection of the data objects, not the raw data itself --

**Output in the Browser:**

```
#<Order:0x007f820823c738>,#<Order:0x007f82082ad708>,#<Order:0x007f82082ace98>,
#<Order:0x007f82082ac718>
```

And I am just trying to get those same objects, but just printed out... like in the RailsCasts tutorial ([Screenshot](http://cl.ly/JGvl))

Here is my Orders_Controller

```
def index
  @search = Order.search(params[:q])
  @orders = @search.result

  @results = @orders

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.csv { render text: @results.to_csv }
  end
end
```

So is there an easy way to convert those data objects into a raw string like in the tutorial?

**EDIT**

Here is my `to_csv` method in my model

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |order|
      csv << order.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please include your `to_csv` method, that's where your problem is, I think.

Comment: Okay, just updated my answer with my `to_csv` method included!

Comment: What is `@search.result`? An array of orders, or...?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. When I use `debugger` right before the `@search.result` call, and prettyprint out the results, the data is in the format that I desire -- http://cl.ly/JHTQ

Answer (score 2):

So I think this is the problem: `@search.result` is an array of Orders, so `@results.to_csv` is calling the `Array#to_csv` method.  Since you're not getting an `ActiveRecord::Relation` you probably need to convert to csv differently.

Create a `ransack_helpers.rb` module in `lib`:

```
module RansackHelpers
  def self.to_csv(ransack_result, options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      result_array = ransack_result.result
      column_names = result_array.first.class.column_names
      csv << column_names
      result_array.each do |item|
        csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In `orders_controller.rb`:

```
def index
  @search = Order.search(params[:q])
  @orders = @search.result

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.csv { render text: RansackHelpers.to_csv(@search) }
  end
end
```

I haven't tested this code, so there might be some issues with it, but I think this is what you want to do.

Comment: Is this helper file going in `/lib/assets/`? or `/lib/tasks`? or just in the `helpers` directory?

Comment: Just put them in the `/lib`, or if you want, you can organize them into subdirectories off of `/lib`. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906932/how-to-create-and-use-a-module-using-ruby-on-rails-3

Comment: Okay, so it seems to be referencing the helper file now properly, however when I include the `RansackHelpers` in my controller, it seems to ignore the query params in the URL and return no records (even though there are records within the search params). When I remove the `include RansackHelpers` in the controller, the query results work properly but I then get a `uninitialized constant OrdersController::RansackHelpers` when I hit the .CSV formatted route. Any ideas? Thanks so much for your help thus far BTW. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Make sure your code matches my example.  Don't include the module.  If it still doesn't work, please add your full controller definition.

Comment: Well, for some reason, I couldn't get it to work properly, so my solution was to render it into a .csv.erb view and manually call each attribute in CSV format. I had a pretty tight deadline to hit for this feature, but I will hopefully explore this solution further for a future update.

Comment: Could you paste in the code you tried (controller and module)?