# Do I Create A Gem Or Module in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have written an app, and I would like to be able to use parts of it in future apps.

Essentially I want to extract parts of my app out into a gem or module, so I can use it for future use.

Do I want to create a gem for this, or a module?

I've read http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#more-files and

[How to create and use a module using Ruby on Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906932/how-to-create-and-use-a-module-using-ruby-on-rails-3)

I want my gem/module to load routes into routes.rb, and I want it to possess views, models, and controllers.  Which is the best option for me, and what are my first steps?

Comment: modules are usually specific to an apps functionality they are essentially helpers. Gems are libraries that act independently. In your case gem would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The best option in you case is to write a gem, because you can add it easily between projects, and even better update the code without copy and paste in all your projects.

You can start by reading the following articles:

1. Oficial guide of rubygems, you can get the info of how a gem is structured http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/
2. After understand how to create a simple gem, please use bundler :D, it have some generators, in Railscasts is an amazing tutorial
   http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler
3. Time to deploy? use this gem to mage your deploys, it have some of best practices, like semantic versioning, tags for every new version https://github.com/svenfuchs/gem-release
4. If you need some example, here is a simple gem that I did, it have a controller and some routes 
   https://github.com/rderoldan1/md_simple_editor