# Trouble on routing Racks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rack

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to route some URLs to some Rack middlewares. That is, if a user try to browse at `http://<my_site_name>.com/api/user/1` the system should consider to run before a Rack file and then proceed in the request.

I have a Rack::Api:User located in the `lib/rack/api/user` folder.

From the RoR official documentation I discovered this:

> ```
>      Mount a Rack-based application to be used within the application.
>
>        mount SomeRackApp, :at => "some_route"
>
>      Alternatively:
>
>        mount(SomeRackApp => "some_route")
>
>      All mounted applications come with routing helpers to access them.
>      These are named after the class specified, so for the above example
>      the helper is either +some_rack_app_path+ or +some_rack_app_url+.
>      To customize this helper's name, use the +:as+ option:
>
>        mount(SomeRackApp => "some_route", :as => "exciting")
>
>      This will generate the +exciting_path+ and +exciting_url+ helpers
>      which can be used to navigate to this mounted app.
> ```

In the routers.rb file I tryed

```
mount "Rack::Api::User", :at => "/api/user/1"
# => ArgumentError missing :action

scope "/api/user/1" do
  mount "Rack::Api::User"
end
# => NoMethodError undefined method `find' for "Rack::Api::User
```

I also tryed

```
match '/api/user/1' => Rack::Api::User
# => Routing Error No route matches "/api/user/1"

match '/api/user/1', :to => Rack::Api::User
# ArgumentError missing :controller
```

but no one works.

---

**UPDATE**

My Rack file is something like this:

```
  module Api
    class User

      def initialize(app)
        @app = app
      end

      def call(env)
        if env["PATH_INFO"] =~ /^\/api\/user\/i
          ...
        else
          @app.call(env)
        end
      end
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're `require`-ing your Rack app somewhere in your bootup process, like in an initializer (keep in mind that files from `lib` are not automatically loaded anymore unless you write code to do so! see [this SO answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073856/rails-3-autoload/4073872#4073872)), then try mounting it without quotes. For example, instead of:

```
mount "Rack::Api::User", :at => "/api/user/1"
```

try

```
mount Rack::Api::User, :at => "/api/user/1"
```

**[Update]**

Here is a link to the changes I made to a basic Rails application that demonstrates both autoloading and mounting a Rack application: https://github.com/BinaryMuse/so_5100999/compare/master...rack

**[Update 2]**

Ah, I see what you're saying now. You want a middleware. I've updated the code at the above URL to implement your application as middleware. `config/initializers/rack.rb` is the file that loads and inserts the middleware. Hope this is what you're looking for!

Comment: Can you make a real example? If my rack file is in '/lib/api/user/', how and where I must 'require' that? P.S.: I wrote code to load the 'lib' path in the 'application.rb' file ('config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)'). P.S. II: I updated the question. P.S.: I tryed your code, but I get same errors.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you want to autoload Rack::Api::User, then the class should be defined in `lib/rack/api/user.rb`. In any case, you can load the file manually by creating a file in `config/initializers/load_my_rack_app.rb` (anything in `config/initializers` is loaded automatically) and put in the code `require "lib/api/user/whatever.rb"`.

Comment: But I get a 'missing :controller'. Is that for the rack statement in the 'user.rb' file?

Comment: @user502052: I've updated my answer with a link to some working code that may help.

Comment: You are great! However the problem, as I suspected, was in the rack statement: I used 'call' instead of 'self.call' and also 'def initialize(app) ...' that (how you wrote in your code) must not be in the code. The only thing that I don't understand is: why use 'self.call' instead of common 'initialize'/'call' methods? And why 'SCRIPT_NAME' instead of 'PATH_INFO'?

Comment: However, now I can not handle anymore incoming request from client applications. I think because in your code there isn't the 'def initialize(app) @app = app end' statement. In fact I don't have anymore access to 'env["HTTP_VARIABLES"]' of incoming requests.

Comment: I'm following you now. I've updated my answer; I think this is what you're talking about.

Comment: I would like to have a middleware that works both for client and service applications. I opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112479/rack-managing-client-and-service-application-responses

Comment: However, in your new code, a request from outside works, but not from "inside" (see the new question).