# rails using file in lib folder - rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require

Normally I put files in the rails lib folder and they seem to be loaded automatically.

I recently tried putting this file : https://gist.github.com/85632 in my lib folder.

From one of my models when I try to do:

```
 ftp = Net::FTPS::Implicit::new(
```

I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Net::FTPS
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/jnylund/Projects/aras/app/models/notifier.rb:372:in `send_ftp_file'
```

I got it to work by adding:
     require 'ftps_implicit'

to the top of my model file.

Why in this case did I need to do this? Is this the right way of doing things?

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 2 will load up files by convention. So when you request:

```
Net::FTPS::Implicit::new
```

... it will look for the file:

```
lib/net/ftps/implicit
```

... to define that class.

I don't think Rails 2 actually loads everything up in the `lib` folder - it only looks in there for a file when something is requested.

Comment: I'd also be wary of defining classes inside Ruby's Net module unless you have a good reason

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 does not load the ./lib directory automatically anymore. If you want to reactivate this behavior in Rails 3
Add the line below to your application config:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

This is also a repost of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073856/rails-3-autoload).

Comment: I believe the original poster was asking specifically about Rails 2