# Including reopened class inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, recurly

I want to add custom methods to the [Recurly::Account](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-ruby) class by reopening it, and then use it in my controller.

something like this:

```
#reopen class
class Recurly::Account

  #my custom method
  def my_meth_1
  end

end

class MyController
  def index
    account = Recurly::Account.find( ... ) #gem method
    account.my_meth_1 #my custom method
  end
end
```

In which file should I reopen the Recurly::Account class and how should it be included in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `lib` folder is a good place for this.

Simply create a file like this

```
# lib/recurly.rb

class Recurly::Account
  def my_meth_1
  end
end
```

> how should it be included in my controller?

You will probably need to turn on autoloading from `lib`, see this topic how to do it [Rails 3 autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073856/rails-3-autoload). After that, you can call it directly from controller.