# Rails: testing custom classes with RSpec

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

Yea, I know that this question is silly, newbee and simple, but I still can't figure it out.
I've created a class (`in app/minions/` directory) to parse auth hashes from 3rd-party services (like google, twitter, etc.). It looks like this.

```
class AuthHash

  def initialize(hash)
    @hash = hash
    @provider = hash[:provider]
    @uid = hash[:uid]
    create_user_hash
  end

 def create_user_hash
   @user_hash = send("parse_hash_from_" << @hash[:provider], @hash)
 end

 def credentials
    {provider: @provider, uid: @uid}
 end

 def user_hash
    @user_hash
 end

 private

   # parse_hash_from_* methods here

end
```

I've added that directory to the autoload path, so I can use it in my controllers. Now I want to write some tests for it.

I'm using RSpec with FactoryGirl for testing. So I started by adding a factory to `spec/factories/` called `auth_hashes.rb` but I can't define a hash as a field in a factory.
So I moved the declaration to the `spec/minions/auth_hash_spec.rb`.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AuthHash do
  before_each do
    auth_hash = AuthHash.new({:provider=>"google_oauth2",:uid=>"123456789",:info=>{:name=>"JohnDoe",:email=>"john@company_name.com",:first_name=>"John",:last_name=>"Doe",:image=>"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/url/photo.jpg"},:credentials=>{:token=>"token",:refresh_token=>"another_token",:expires_at=>1354920555,:expires=>true},:extra=>{:raw_info=>{:id=>"123456789",:email=>"user@domain.example.com",:verified_email=>true,:name=>"JohnDoe",:given_name=>"John",:family_name=>"Doe",:link=>"https://plus.google.com/123456789",:picture=>"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/url/photo.jpg",:gender=>"male",:birthday=>"0000-06-25",:locale=>"en",:hd=>"company_name.com"}}})
  end
end
```

But still it does not seem to work.

I know this should be alot simpler then I'm trying to do, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to that new spec (`spec/minions/auth_hash_spec.rb`) file at the top:

```
require Rails.root.to_s + '/app/minions/myhash.rb'
```

And then write your tests.

Comment: Can't I just add `require 'auth_hash'` since it's in the autoload path?

Comment: Unless you setup Rails to autoload your new directory, it's not going to autoload it. Refer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073856/rails-3-autoload

Comment: Did you read my comment and the question? I did it to autoload. So, yes, just simple require seems working. But I though there should be a way to move the prototype declarations from the test to some kind of a factory.

Comment: I just tested if everything is autoloaded in /app by creating a class and trying to instantiate it. I had to require it to instantiate the class. So everything is not autoloaded under /app in Rails 3.2.13. Are you using a previous version of Rails?