# YAML library not working in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have this code in an app/lib folder:

```
require 'yaml'

class YamlParser
  def parse
    data = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml")
    require 'pry' ; binding.pry
    data[:production]
  end
end

YamlParser.new.parse
```

Why isn't it working? I am getting this error message:

```
uninitialized constant YamlParser::Rails (NameError)
```

Comment: Have you autoloaded the file and also before you use this you may have to require the file. `require 'yaml_parser.rb'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, my class YamlParser was located in a file called "yaml_parse.rb" and not "yaml_parser.rb". I am bad at naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: but I put my file in app/lib which should be eagerly loaded right?

Comment: nope, it doesn't as of Rails 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073856/rails-3-autoload

Comment: No, I think it does load app/lib. I made an app/lib folder. The post is referring to just the straight Rails.root/lib folder.

Comment: My fault! By `app/lib` I understood `project_folder/lib`. Anyway, I would encourage you to use `project_folder/lib`.