# Rails 3 - Help! Subdomains - Users Cannot Logout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, railscasts

I've followed the ascii cast up at http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

I've set the :domain option to :all in session store:

`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_bloggit_session', :domain => :all`

Now my users cannot logout.

Any ideas why? I've tried deleting all cookies and then trying again, etc.

I can login, and my session is carried across subdomains, but I can't logout.

I am using rails 3, and authlogic for authentication.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show us the relevant code, please?

Comment: It's just this one line in session_store.rb that's causing/not causing problems - >>> Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_bloggit_session', :domain => :all <<

Comment: Put it in your question then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Specify the Domain.

I had the exact same issue and the culprit was using `:domain => :all`.

You'd think that would be all you need but it [seems to cause some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060333/what-does-rails-3-session-store-domain-all-really-do) so I had to manually specify the domain with a preceding dot (`.`), like so:

`:domain => '.lvh.me'`

This fixed the issue in development. You can use different ways to set this in your various environments but I landed on something like this:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
  :key => '_bloggit_session',
  :domain => { production:  '.bloggit.com',
               staging:     '.bloggitstaging.com',
               development: '.lvh.me' }.fetch(Rails.env.to_sym)
```