# session variable getting deleted when subdomains switch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out what to do about my @session variable getting deleted when I log a user in from signin.website.com to user.website.com.

I tried everything that SO suggested already.

I tried setting the session_store.rb file like so:

```
:domain => :all
```

that didn't work (still deleted the session variable) and then I tried

```
:domain => '.website.com'
```

that didn't work either! Am I doing something wrong? I'm on rails 3.0.1

How do I get the session variable to stick? It seems that setting those settings didn't actually do anything. I checked the cookies and they still say signin.website.com.

The cookies are still not be stored properly. I rebooted my server and everything.

I finally got :domain => ".local.com" working...it wasn't working because I was on my local machine. However, :all still doesn't work.

Comment: try this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060333/what-does-rails-3-session-store-domain-all-really-do][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060333/what-does-rails-3-session-store-domain-all-really-do

Comment: that's for multiple domains...i am in need of multiple subdomains