# WWW and non-WWW URL. Two different sites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am noticing that my sites session cookies are different between the two. If someone logs in on the `www.mysite.com` they are not logged in on the `non www` site. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `config/initializers/session_store.rb` add `, :domain => ".yourdomain.com"` to the end of the `Application.config.session_store` line.

Answer (score 1):

Add domain for cookie like this:

```
cookies[:key] = {:value=>val,:domain=>'.mysite.com'}
```

Comment: I'm using a `session` can I do this there?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060333/what-does-rails-3-session-store-domain-all-really-do` look this.