# How split iframe and non-iframe sessions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, iframe, cookies

I have rails application on my website (A*) and application on different resource (B*) based on iframe of application A*.
When I logged in from iframe app B* then rails store my session in cookies and rewrite old session started from pure application A* (if it is).
Now when I go to application A* then i will be logged in by session from cookies written by B*.

How I may avoid it?
I want store different sessions for iframe and non-iframe (B* and A*) apps.

Comment: Are A* and B* on the same domain?  This like might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060333/what-does-rails-3-session-store-domain-all-really-do They have the opposite problem and want to share a session but you can see the rails configuration.

Comment: @Derek A* and B* iframe linked to same domain. It didn't help :(