# Rails - Loosing cookies after form submission to another url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

In my Rails 4 app, I have a form sitting on a domain that follows this format - http://dev.example.com.  The action of the form is set to POST to a different domain - https://admin.example.com.  In that POST, my controller action sets a cookie to sign in the current user.  That is all working as expected.  I can print out cookies[:remember_token] and current_user.  However, when I redirect to another page on https://admin.example.com, I lose my remember_token cookie which causes my current_user lookup to fail.

Is this expected behavior for cookies?  I know cookies are attached to domains, but I would think my remember_token cookie would live with the admin domain, and a redirect to the admin domain would retain the cookie.  Please let me know if this question doesn't make sense and I can provide more information.  Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: When I view cookies in Chrome (chrome://settings/cookies), I don't see remember_token being set on either domain.  If the same form starts on the https://admin.example.com, then everything is fine - cookie gets set and user stays signed in.  Is Rails preventing cookies from being set while transitioning to another domain, or is it the browser?

Comment: Here is a really good guide to cookie domains and all the (IE) bugs and quirks http://erik.io/blog/2014/03/04/definitive-guide-to-cookie-domains/

Comment: And here is how you set the cookie to `.example.com` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060333/what-does-rails-3-session-store-domain-all-really-do

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `:domain => :all` to the session intializer:

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_app_name_session', :domain => :all
```