# Rails ActionCable Request Origins Subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actioncable

I'm building a SaaS platform with the apartment gem and am introducing ActionCable for chat functionality.  I have most of the chat functionality built, but when transmitting to the channel I get the following:

```
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-01 08:49:53 -0600
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-01 08:49:53 -0600
```

I'm using this code in app/channels/connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      tenant = request.subdomain
      Apartment::Tenant.switch!(tenant)
      logger.add_tags "ActionCable", "User #{current_user.id}", "Tenant #{tenant}"
    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user
        if current_user = env['warden'].user
          current_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

This in theory should switch the Tenant and get Actioncable transmitting on the right subdomain.  But I'm still getting these errors.

I'm also using Devise and am logged in as a user so there's no reason that I can think of why the connection was rejected since it's looking up the current user and validating that the user is a logged in devise user based off of the warden ENV.

I'm wondering since I have subdomains in play if I should be configuring the request origins in a certain fashion.

To test this I hardcoded one of my subdomains that I'm using on the lvh.me localhost domain as such:

```
  Rails.application.config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http://acme.lvh.me:3000']
```

I was wondering if the allowed_request_origins has something to do with this and if so, how can I use regex to allow for any subdomain to the lvh.me:3000 url/domainspace?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

With the help of a friend we learned that we needed to switch tenants prior to establishing the connection.  Here is the connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      tenant = request.subdomain
      Apartment::Tenant.switch!(tenant)
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags "ActionCable", "User #{current_user.id}", "Tenant #{tenant}"
    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user
        if current_user = env['warden'].user
          current_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

To handle the regex portion in development.rb to handle the request origins I did this:

```
  Rails.application.config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http:\/\/*.lvh.me:3000*']
```

So far it's working and AC is transmitting properly with Apartment on subdomains.  At least in development.

Comment: I'm attempting to use ActionCable on subdomains; user must be signed-in with Devise to open channel page. When in root domain, `env['warden']` supplies current_user, but when in subdomain, ActionCable.connect finds `env['warden']` nil. Any way around this?

Comment: @dlehman that's probably why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060333/what-does-rails-3-session-store-domain-all-really-do

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails