# Rails share cookies across only 2 subdomains, and use separate cookie for all other subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Rails 7 SaSS app using Devise for authentication, that signs up a new user on the `www.my-site.com` subdomain and redirects them to the actual app after signup at `dashboard.my-site.com`.

I'm able to accomplish this easy enough with the following session_store.rb code:

`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp_session", domain: ["dashboard.my-site.com", "www.my-site.com"], tld_length: 2`

But the problem is that my app allows users to have custom subdomains - which should have totally separate cookies - for example, `a-customer-subdomain.my-site.com`

So my thought is that I will actually need to set the :cookie_store dynamically sometime earlier - like in Middleware - so we use one setting for `www` and `dashboard` subdomain and an entirely different one for any other subdomain or domain. This is where I find myself stuck though. How can I go about making these adjustments?

Comment: You may try writing a custom code in the rack middleware. check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/4065929/2488801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at "[What does Rails 3 `session_store domain :all` really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4060333/6309)", but also "[Building a Rails App With Multiple Subdomains](https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/03/04/building-a-rails-app-with-multiple-subdomains.html#sharing-session-between-different-subdomains)" by [Prathamesh Sonpatki](https://github.com/prathamesh-sonpatki) (March 2020), you should indeed use a middleware to dynamically set the cookie domain based on the incoming request.

```rb
# lib/middleware/dynamic_cookie_domain.rb
class DynamicCookieDomain
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    host = env["HTTP_HOST"].split(':').first
    Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp_session", domain: custom_domain(host), tld_length: 2
    @app.call(env)
  end

  private

  def custom_domain(host)
    case host
    when 'www.my-site.com', 'dashboard.my-site.com'
      ['dashboard.my-site.com', 'www.my-site.com']
    else
      host
    end
  end
end
```

This middleware will set the session cookie domain to `['dashboard.my-site.com', 'www.my-site.com']` if the request is coming from either of those hosts. For any other host, it will set the session cookie domain to the host of the request.

You will need to add this middleware to your middleware stack. You can do this in your application configuration:

```rb
# config/application.rb
require_relative '../lib/middleware/dynamic_cookie_domain'

module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
    config.middleware.use DynamicCookieDomain
    # ...
  end
end
```

This will insert the `DynamicCookieDomain` middleware into your middleware stack, ensuring that it is run for every request.

That should address the requirement of having different cookie settings for `www` and `dashboard` subdomains versus any other subdomain.

The `custom_domain` method in the middleware checks the host of the incoming request.

- If the host is either `www.my-site.com` or `dashboard.my-site.com`, it sets the cookie domain to `['dashboard.my-site.com', 'www.my-site.com']`. This means that the session cookie will be shared between these two subdomains.
- For any other host (which would be any other subdomain or domain), it sets the cookie domain to the host of the request. This means that the session cookie will be specific to that subdomain or domain and will not be shared with `www.my-site.com` or `dashboard.my-site.com`.

This dynamic setting of the cookie domain based on the incoming request should allow you to have one setting for `www` and `dashboard` subdomains and a different setting for any other subdomain or domain.

---

This is slightly different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4065929/6309), which sets the cookie domain to the second-level domain (e.g., `my-site.com`) if the request is coming from a subdomain, and to `:all` otherwise. This would share cookies across all subdomains of `my-site.com`.

In contrast, here, the cookie domain is set to `['dashboard.my-site.com', 'www.my-site.com']` if the request is coming from either of those hosts, and to the host of the request otherwise. This shares cookies between `dashboard.my-site.com` and `www.my-site.com`, but uses separate cookies for all other subdomains.

---

> I haven't been able to figure out how to change the session_storage key dynamically

Attempting to dynamically alter the session store configuration within a middleware seems ineffective, likely because the session store configuration is initialized when the Rails application starts up, and subsequent modifications within the middleware do not have the desired impact.

A potential solution to this challenge could be to directly manipulate the [`ActionDispatch::Request`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) object's [session options](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-session_options-3D) within the middleware, rather than attempting to reconfigure the session store.

Try and modify the `DynamicCookieDomain` middleware to alter the session options of the `ActionDispatch::Request` object:

```rb
# lib/middleware/dynamic_cookie_domain.rb
class DynamicCookieDomain
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
    host = request.host

    domain = custom_domain(host)
    request.session_options[:domain] = domain

    @app.call(request.env)
  end

  private

  def custom_domain(host)
    case host
    when 'www.my-site.com', 'dashboard.my-site.com'
      '.my-site.com'
    else
      host
    end
  end
end
```

Make sure the middleware is loaded and used in your application:

```rb
# config/application.rb
require_relative '../lib/middleware/dynamic_cookie_domain'

module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
    config.middleware.use DynamicCookieDomain
    # ...
  end
end
```

With that `DynamicCookieDomain` middleware, the `call` method creates an `ActionDispatch::Request` object from the `env` hash, and then modifies the `session_options` of the `Request` object to set the desired domain. The middleware then calls the next item in the middleware stack with the updated `env` hash from the `Request` object.

That should change the session options on a per-request basis, rather than globally reconfiguring the session store.

Comment: So after doing everything possible to integrate this solution, I've found that it doesn't actually work. The problem is that setting `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp_session", domain: custom_domain(host), tld_length: 2` in the middleware has no effect. Furthermore, even setting `env['rack.session.options'][:key] =` in the middleware directly has no effect. I haven't been able to figure out how to change the session_storage key dynamically.

Comment: @D-Nice OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment and propose an alternative approach for you to test.