# Rails 7, dynamically setting the session cookie by domain & subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, middleware, rack, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Rails 7 SaaS app using Devise for authentication, that signs up a new user on the [www.my-site.com](http://www.my-site.com) subdomain and redirects them to the actual app after signup at dashboard.my-site.com. Also, my multi-tenant app gives subdomains to each user, so user-10.my-site.com, which must have it's own separate cookies too.

I wrote custom middleware to solve this problem (mostly outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76499358/216363)), but it turns out that this doesn't appear to work anymore, since at least Rails 5.

You can try to set the cookie with `env['rack.session.options'][:key] = "my-dynamic-key"` or `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp_session", domain: custom_domain(host), tld_length: 2` - **but the actually cookie on the client never changes.** From what I can tell, it's no longer possible to set cookies dynamically using middleware with Rails. The cookie attributes (name, domain, etc.) always remain as the defaults provided when the application begins.

There are plenty of answers on the internet that reference this old way of dynamically setting cookies. But it just doesn't work. I created a new Rails project to ensure that it wasn't something in my project that was breaking it - and alas, the custom middleware didn't work there either.

I've spent the last several days trying to understand **why** it doesn't work anymore, and what a potential resolution might be, but I have no answers. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where should we start here? Rails still provides the `config.session_store` option which allows you to plug in any backend that you want to for session storage. So its certainly possible. Rails 6.1 introduced `config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection` which defaults to `:lax` which could explain the changed behavior. I don't think we are going to get any further unless you can actually present some code and do enough debugging to narrow the problem down to something more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: For example use breakpoints, logging or a test with mocking to ensure that your middleware is actually being used in the application. Then check what the session identifier cookies are actually being set to on different domains (you can fake this via Ngrok).

Comment: @max The logs definitely show that the middleware is being used and the code is executed with every request. But just stepping back, I created a new rails project and created a controller and action, and simply added `request.env['rack.session.options'][:key] = "testing"` into the action. The code runs, but the key of the cookie on the clientside is never "testing." The key on the cookie on the client remains the default, which in this case is `_testapp_session` because it isn't configured in an initializer.