# Correct way to share login sessions across subdomains in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

All the info I've found on the internet about this says to use something like

```
Login::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_login_session', :domain => '.domain.com'
```

And use the same key for all the subdomains that I want to share that session.  When I do this, the authentication is not being passed between subdomains.  In fact, when I visit any of the supposedly shared sessions, the initial session gets overwritten

i.e. on login.domain.com, I run the authentication, which returns the user name and session user_id.  I then go to sub.domain.com, which should return the same info as login.domain.com, but does not.  Following this, I go back to login.domain.com and I am no longer authenticated there, either.

On sub.domain.com, the session_store.rb file looks like:

```
Something::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_login_session', :domain => '.domain.com'
```

I have used :all for the :domain value, as well, with the same outcome.  And if I remove the :domain setting on the above, then the initial session does not get overwritten, but it also does not get shared.

When I look at the cookies in Cookie Editor for Firefox, both subdomains are using the same cookie name, but the authentication is not being shared.  It's a pretty basic Users table, and I am using OpenID and OAuth to perform authentication with Omniauth

Comment: You can't share login (or any) info with cookies this way, as subdomains cannot see each others (subdomains) cookies. The double dot solution works if the original site is on "domain.com" and THEN you go down onto one of your subdomains, THEN will the browser send all top-level cookies to the subdomain request. A sub.domain.com cookie will never be sent to any.domain.com

Comment: Anyway if I were you, I would just make a simple ajax proxy and put it to all subdomains. It is about 15-20 lines of code in PHP or Ruby, but if you don't want to code, then a well configured Nginx will do the job.

Comment: @karatedog - I see, I was hoping to abstract all login methods to a separate login application running on it's own login.* subdomain. but if I understand you correctly, I need to do authentication on domain.com in order for sub.domain.com to use the session?  I have seen sites that use a login.domain to authenticate with *.domain elsewhere.  Maybe they are storing session info in the database though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*update:* the suggested solution is not that ugly after all, ad-exchanges and DSPs/SSPs use the same technique to exchange a visitor's session ID so they can better target the visitor with ads (the next time that visitor pops up in their network again)

---

If you can circumvent the browser cross-domain barrier, you can do it. For example, JSONP is specifically built for this purpose. And yes, session info is always stored centrally, otherwise if you get a request with a session ID of "zigzag", how can you check if it is valid?

"Those" sites that authenticate on login.domain.com might use an ajax proxy, or use other method to get through the cross-domain problem.

The oldest "trick" is to create a hook in your application that looks like an image, as images can be loaded from everywhere.

For example, on *login.domain.com* you authenticate the user, sent to the server and back with a response, and a cookie will be stored under *login.domain.com* with the session ID (which is stored in the server as well). Then - from Javascript - you GET an image, with the session ID attached, like http://any.domain.com/path/image.jpg?sessionID=abcd -> any cookies sent back in the response will be stored under *any.domain.com*

Another solution <strike>- which is as ugly as the previous -</strike> is to use a hidden iframe to call to any.domain.com (when a successful authentication happens), that request will return a response, and its cookies will be written under the any.domain.com domain.

If you have a multitudes of subdomains, and you can complicate your architecture a bit, I highly advise that you create a proxy, and make it available to every subdomain on the same IP address. Then no matter where the user comes in, the authentication process will always be the same, for every subdomain.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason prefixing the domain with a dot did not work (rails 3.2.11) for me either. It took a piece of custom Middleware to fix it. A summary of that solution is below.

**tl;dr:** You need to write a custom Rack Middleware. You need add it into your `conifg/environments/[production|development].rb`. This is on Rails 3.2.11

Cookie sessions are usually stored only for your top level domain.

If you look in `Chrome -> Settings -> Show advanced settings… -> Privacy/Content settings… -> All cookies and site data… -> Search {yourdomain.com}` You can see that there will be separate entries for `sub1.yourdomain.com` and `othersub.yourdomain.com` and `yourdomain.com`

The challenge is to use the same session store file across all subdomains.

### Step 1: Add Custom Middleware Class

This is where [Rack Middleware](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) comes in. Some relevant rack & rails resources:

- [Railscasts about Rack](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware?view=asciicast)
- [Railsguide for Rack](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html)
- Rack documentation for [sesssions abstractly](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Session/Abstract/ID.html) and for [cookie sessions](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Session/Cookie.html)

Here is a custom class that you should add in the `lib`
**This was written by [@Nader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166918/nader) and you all should thank him**

```
# Custom Domain Cookie
#
# Set the cookie domain to the custom domain if it's present
class CustomDomainCookie
  def initialize(app, default_domain)
    @app = app
    @default_domain = default_domain
  end

  def call(env)
    host = env["HTTP_HOST"].split(':').first
    env["rack.session.options"][:domain] = custom_domain?(host) ? ".#{host}" : "#{@default_domain}"
    @app.call(env)
  end

  def custom_domain?(host)
    host !~ /#{@default_domain.sub(/^\./, '')}/i
  end
end
```

Basically what this does is that it will map all of your cookie session data back onto the exact same cookie file that is equal to your root domain.

### Step 2: Add To Rails Config

Now that you have a custom class in lib, make sure are autoloading it. If that meant nothing to you, look here: [Rails 3 autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073856/rails-3-autoload)

The first thing is to make sure that you are system-wide using a cookie store. In **`config/application.rb`** we tell Rails to use a cookie store.

```
# We use a cookie_store for session data
config.session_store :cookie_store,
                     :key => '_yourappsession',
                     :domain => :all
```

The reason this is here is mentioned here is because of the `:domain => :all` line. There are other people that have suggested to specify `:domain => ".yourdomain.com"` instead of `:domain => :all`. For some reason this did not work for me and I needed the custom Middleware class as described above.

Then in your **`config/environments/production.rb`** add:

```
config.middleware.use "CustomDomainCookie", ".yourdomain.com"
```

Note that the preceding dot is necessary. See "[sub-domain cookies, sent in a parent domain request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865345/sub-domain-cookies-sent-in-a-parent-domain-request)" for why.

Then in your **`config/environments/development.rb`** add:

```
config.middleware.use "CustomDomainCookie", ".lvh.me"
```

The lvh.me trick maps onto localhost. It's awesome. See [this Railscast about subdomains](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) and [this note](http://pastebin.com/GUrn7vvE) for more info.

Hopefully that should do it. I honestly am not entirely sure why the process is this convoluted, as I feel cross subdomain sites are common. If anyone has any further insights into the reasons behind each of these steps, please enlighten us in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

After you configure Rails session to be shared across subdomains using the line you mentioned above, once you are in a subdomain you can access the cookies from the domain by setting, through Javascript, the document.domain property to your domain.

Say you are in mysubdomain.domain.com, you will set:
document.domain = "domain.com";
Now, you will be able to access the cookies from domain.com.

(Note that you cannot set the document.domain to any other subdomain, due to the same origin policies)