# Rails 3 session resets when redirecting to custom domain page but session stays for heroku default domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, heroku

I am using Rails 3's session variable to store some data.
Eg.  session[:token] = user_token

This session variable exists throughout a single session if I access my app via the heroku domain.  (example.heroku.com)   However, if I access via the custom domain, (www.example.com) 
the session variable clears everytime I redirect to another page within the domain.

I could not figure out what is the problem
I have tried implementing it with both :cookie_store and :active_record_store, but the same problem persists. I even tried setting the :domain for :cookie_store

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_my_app_session', :domain => :all
```

No luck yet. Please let me know if I missed setting up anything.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set a default domain in this case. 
`ActionController::CgiRequest::DEFAULT_SESSION_OPTIONS[:session_domain] = '.example.com'`

For more in details please read this blog [Cookie-Handling](http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2008/01/21/cookie-handling-in-multi-domain-applications-in-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: mmm, this doesn't work for Rails 3. I get a /app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActionController::CgiRequest (NameError)

Comment: I found one ans which relates to your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123325/correct-way-to-share-login-sessions-across-subdomains-in-rails-3