# Share session (cookies) between subdomains in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I have an app setup where each user belongs to a company, and that company has a subdomain (I am using basecamp style subdomains). The problem that I am facing is that rails is creating multiple cookies (one for lvh.me and another for subdomain.lvh.me) which is causing quite a few breaks in my application(such as flash messages being persistent though out all requests once signed in).

I have this in my /cofig/initilizers/session_store.rb file:

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_application_devise_session', domain: :all
```

The domain: :all seems to be the standard answer I found on Google, but that doesn't seem to be working for me. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As it turns outs 'domain: all' creates a cookie for all the different subdomains that are visited during that session (and it ensures that they are passed around between request). If no domain argument is passed, it means that a new cookie is created for every different domain that is visited in the same session and the old one gets discarded. What I needed was a single cookie that is persistent throughout the session, even when the domain changes. Hence, passing `domain: "lvh.me"` solved the problem in development. This creates a single cookie that stays there between different subdomains.

For anyone needing further explanation, this is a great link: 
http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/

Comment: Thanks Dude.. I've been facing this issue on one of my projects.. Finally found the solution..

Comment: Be sure to use the same `config.secret_key_base` across all your applications, or else it won't be able to decode the cookie.

Comment: I don't see any questions related to this for Rails 4. Do you know if this has changed. I can't get it to work with my project. It keeps recreating the cookies. Thanks.

Comment: What if I want to use `CacheStore` to store sessions in memcached?

Comment: With Rails4, I found that this only worked for subdomains with dashes but not with underscores: `Appname::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_appname_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2`

Comment: @user1515295 subdomains cannot have underscores, this is the DNS standard, nothing to do with Rails.

Answer (score 72):

http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/

> "The part you want to watch out for here is that if you set :domain =>
>   :all like is recommend in some places, it simply won’t work unless
>   you’re using localhost. :all defaults to a TLD length of 1, which
>   means if you’re testing with Pow (myapp.dev) it won’t work either
>   because that is a TLD of length 2."

In other words you need:

```
 App.config.session_store ... , :domain => :all, :tld_length => 2
```

Also a good idea to clear your cookies

Comment: This is the best answer because the one change works in all environments (app.com and app.dev). Custom middleware is not necessary.

Also good point to clear cookies!

Comment: I'm using rails4, this config does not work in my case, it still requires me to login everytime I change subdomain, <APP_NAME>::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, domain: :all

Comment: you are missing the `, :tld_length => 2`

Comment: Be sure to use the same `config.secret_key_base` across all your applications, or else it won't be able to decode the cookie.

Comment: `:domain => :all` won't work in Rails 4, try `domain => 'lvh.me', tld_length = 2`. It workd for me

Comment: With Rails 4.2 I got good results with just `domain: :all, tld_length: 2` while using the `lvh.me` domain.

Comment: As shown in the Rails action controller code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28976155/135101), the `tld_length` becomes part of a regex. Thus, you should be able to use e.g. `:tld_length => '1,'` to allow a TLD length of 1+. Can any confirm?

Comment: @TylerCollier it seems to work (via browser testing only) on rails 4.2 + devise 3.5.1. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: "Also a good idea to clear your cookies" - cannot thank you enough, was driving me crazy that flashes were not working with subdomains locally.

Answer (score 26):

I was looking for a way to solve this problem without having to explicitly state the domain name, so I could hop between localhost, lvh.me, and whichever domains I would use in production without having to keep editing the session_store.rb file. However, setting "domain: :all" didn't seem to be working for me.

Ultimately I found that I needed to state the tld_length (top level domain length) in that expression. The default tld_length is 1 while example.lvh.me has a tld_length of 2 and 127.0.0.1.xip.io has a tld_length of 5, for example. So what I had in the session_store.rb file for subdomains on lvh.me in development and whatever else in production was the below.

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_MyApp_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

Hope this helps someone, as it took me a long time to find this answer!

Answer (score 19):

For some reason replacing `:all` with the domain did not work (rails 3.2.11) for me. It took a piece of custom Middleware to fix it. A summary of that solution is below.

**tl;dr:** You need to write a custom Rack Middleware. You need add it into your `conifg/environments/[production|development].rb`. This is on Rails 3.2.11

Cookie sessions are usually stored only for your top level domain.

If you look in `Chrome -> Settings -> Show advanced settings… -> Privacy/Content settings… -> All cookies and site data… -> Search {yourdomain.com}` You can see that there will be separate entries for `sub1.yourdomain.com` and `othersub.yourdomain.com` and `yourdomain.com`

The challenge is to use the same session store file across all subdomains.

### Step 1: Add Custom Middleware Class

This is where [Rack Middleware](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) comes in. Some relevant rack & rails resources:

- [Railscasts about Rack](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware?view=asciicast)
- [Railsguide for Rack](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html)
- Rack documentation for [sesssions abstractly](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Session/Abstract/ID.html) and for [cookie sessions](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Session/Cookie.html)

Here is a custom class that you should add in the `lib`
**This was written by [@Nader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166918/nader) and you all should thank him**

```
# Custom Domain Cookie
#
# Set the cookie domain to the custom domain if it's present
class CustomDomainCookie
  def initialize(app, default_domain)
    @app = app
    @default_domain = default_domain
  end

  def call(env)
    host = env["HTTP_HOST"].split(':').first
    env["rack.session.options"][:domain] = custom_domain?(host) ? ".#{host}" : "#{@default_domain}"
    @app.call(env)
  end

  def custom_domain?(host)
    host !~ /#{@default_domain.sub(/^\./, '')}/i
  end
end
```

Basically what this does is that it will map all of your cookie session data back onto the exact same cookie file that is equal to your root domain.

### Step 2: Add To Rails Config

Now that you have a custom class in lib, make sure are autoloading it. If that meant nothing to you, look here: [Rails 3 autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073856/rails-3-autoload)

The first thing is to make sure that you are system-wide using a cookie store. In **`config/application.rb`** we tell Rails to use a cookie store.

```
# We use a cookie_store for session data
config.session_store :cookie_store,
                     :key => '_yourappsession',
                     :domain => :all
```

The reason this is here is mentioned here is because of the `:domain => :all` line. There are other people that have suggested to specify `:domain => ".yourdomain.com"` instead of `:domain => :all`. For some reason this did not work for me and I needed the custom Middleware class as described above.

Then in your **`config/environments/production.rb`** add:

```
config.middleware.use "CustomDomainCookie", ".yourdomain.com"
```

Note that the preceding dot is necessary. See "[sub-domain cookies, sent in a parent domain request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865345/sub-domain-cookies-sent-in-a-parent-domain-request)" for why.

Then in your **`config/environments/development.rb`** add:

```
config.middleware.use "CustomDomainCookie", ".lvh.me"
```

The lvh.me trick maps onto localhost. It's awesome. See [this Railscast about subdomains](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) and [this note](http://pastebin.com/GUrn7vvE) for more info.

Hopefully that should do it. I honestly am not entirely sure why the process is this convoluted, as I feel cross subdomain sites are common. If anyone has any further insights into the reasons behind each of these steps, please enlighten us in the comments.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with multiple top level domain? I have a product that runs in different countries. Here we're assuming the default domain is yourdomain.com, but what if it was supposed to work for .be .sv .fr .com.br .com.ar and others? Thanks.

Comment: I just can't get this to work. I am developing in rails 4 and it seems like rials just gently ignores all the code above. It just does not want to share the session across subdomains.

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm Be sure to use the same `config.secret_key_base` across all your applications, or else it won't be able to decode the cookie.

Answer (score 19):

I came across this while looking for the simplest way to set the cookie to be the root domain.  It seems there is some misinformation about the `:all` option when passed as the domain option.  For most domains, it will actually work as expected, setting the cookie to the root domain (e.g. `.example.com` for `test.example.com`).  I think most people experienced issues since they're using the domain `lvh.me` to test.  The regex used by rails to find a top level domain is defined to be `DOMAIN_REGEXP = /[^.]*\.([^.]*|..\...|...\...)$/`.  If you note the last part, you can see that rails interprets `lvh.me` as a TLD similar to `com.au`.  If your use case needs `lvh.me` to work, then the `:all` option won't work properly, however, it appears to be the simplest and best option for most domains.

TL;DR, the correct answer here, assuming you aren't developing on a 3 letter domain (or any domain that confuses the above regex) is to use `:all`.

Comment: Thank you, this finally helped me understand why so many answers were recommending a tld_length of 2 but why I didn't need to!

Comment: This answer needs to be higher up. Thanks, sir.

Comment: "lvh.me as a TLD similar to com.au" BTW Rails should indeed interpret .me the same way as it's also a country domain (Montenegro).

Answer (score 8):

**Rails 4.x** (also should be fine with Rails 5/6 versions)

[How to get lvh.me:3000 and subdomain in localhost (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521114/unable-to-determine-ip-address-from-host-name/36522401#36522401)

Development: I have shared cookies to adding `.lvh.me` into `session_store.rb`,

It will be shared between subdomains on localhost `admin.lvh.me:3000`, `lvh.me:3000` and so on...

```
#config/initializers/session_store.rb

domain = Rails.env.production? ? ".domain_name.com" : ".lvh.me"

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
                      key: '_app_name_session', domain: domain
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_application_devise_session', domain: 'lvh.me'
```

)

basically we are saying have single cookie for base domain and just ignore sub domain..though this approach has some flaws still ...

Answer (score 2):

support rails5

if you want it works with any domain:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

To configure per environment you could use the following:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session', domain: {
  production: '.example.com',
  development: '.example.dev'
}.fetch(Rails.env.to_sym, :all)
```

Ref: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Redis for session store.

```
if Rails.env.development?
    Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store, {
       servers: [
        { host: 'localhost', port: 6379},
      ],
      key: '_app_session',
      expire_after: 1.day,
      domain: :all
    }

else
    Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store, {
       servers: [
        { host: HOST_URL, port: PORT},
      ],
      key: '_app_session',
      expire_after: 1.day,
      domain: '.domain.com',
      tld_length: 2
    }
    
end
```