# Rails 3.2 - Writing cookie value without encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We have a few web applications that share a cookie value `ssoid`.

When the user logs into our Rails application, we want to set the `ssoid` value in the cookie but Rails is URL encoding the value by default.

```
cookies[:ssoid] = session[:token]
```

Value written to the cookie store is

```
ABCpRyan0fLwMamiT%2F9GGk2o%2FAPckq1C8PbHCotxmgUk%3D
```

instead of

```
ABCpRyan0fLwMamiT/9GGk2o/APckq1C8PbHCotxmgUk=
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the [memcached gem](https://github.com/evan/memcached) to store cookies in one commun place and share that cookie across multiple apps you can also take a look at [sharing session across rails apps on different subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314155/sharing-session-across-rails-apps-on-different-subdomains) as a subdomain is seen as a different site or app

I hope that I could help.