# Share Session for all domains in rails 2.3.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

My code is here in `config/environment.rb` file

```
ActionController::Base.session_options[:domain] ="mydomain"
```

But i want to make session for all domains. Please help me i am using `ruby 1.8.7` and `Rails 2.3.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want sessions to continue across other domains on your site.

You can edit the session_store.rb file and add a "." to the domain to make it work across subdomains. You can also change the :tld if you need to.

```
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_YourApp_session', :domain => '.mydomain', :tld => 2
```

More info that might help you out: ([Share session (cookies) between subdomains in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails))