# User gets logged out when he's on a page with subdomain.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a `User`, set up with `Devise`.

User can have his own page (with subdomain). 
Like: `awesomeuser.domain.com`

On localhost after sign in I can visit both root path and path with subdomain - and he's signed in.

But on production server when he visits path with subdomain - he gets signed out.

Does anyone know what it can be caused by?

Since it works on local machine - I know it's sessions, but what exactly?

Here's my `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_MyApp_session', domain: :all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this problem - the issue is your `session` can only be passed between one domain. The solution is to use `domain: :all`, however, as you're using `subdomain`, you have to specify the level of domains the cookies will be valid for, hence `tld_length: 2`

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_MyApp_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

We found the answer here: [Share session (cookies) between subdomains in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails/15009883#15009883)