# How to create subdomain with custom domain in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, subdomain

My app is on domain: `abc.com`, Now I have another domain: `mydomain.com`. I can routes `mydomain.com` to a controller in app. But how I can routes `blog.mydomain.com` to a controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to map a subdomain to an existing controller action in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507770/how-to-map-a-subdomain-to-an-existing-controller-action-in-localhost)

Comment: Are you asking about how to setup the DNS entries or about how to write your `routes.rb`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @spickermann I want to know how to write in routes.rb. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is this

```rb
  constraints subdomain: 'blog' do

  end
```

Furthermore; you need to notify your hosts about this when testing locally(dev environment).