# Trying to use CORS and XSRF on different domains

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cross-domain, csrf

I have a frontend and a backend app. They are in different domains (subdomain).
The frontend app does a first request (GET) to get some server-side information, basically `session_id` and `XSRF-TOKEN` cookies.

The situation is:

`myapp.com cookies: _session_id
api.myapp.com cookies: XSRF-TOKEN`

So, my frontend app gets the `_session_id` cookie but it doesn't get the `XSRF-TOKEN`. When I try to get the `XSRF-TOKEN` to put it on the header like `X-XSRF-TOKEN` it isn't possible because they're different domains.

Any good soul to help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to consider the following:  [Share session (cookies) between subdomains in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails/15009883#15009883)

```
#config/initializers/session_store.rb
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_yourapp_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking a little bit further at rails I just needed to share the cookies between the subdomains like this:

```
cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = { value: form_authenticity_token, domain: '.myapp.com'}
```