# Sharing session between Rails 2.3 and Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

I have two applications running on different rails versions; rails 2.3.18 and rails 4.2.1. I need to share the session between them so that logging into one application would also login into the other. I have the following configuration:

#### Rails 2.3

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
ActionController::Base.session = {
  key: '_custom_session',
  secret: 'xyz' }

# config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb
ActionController::Base.cookie_verifier_secret = 'xyz'
```

#### Rails 4.2

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_custom_session'
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :marshal
Rails.application.config.secret_token = 'xyz'

# config/secrets.yml
# Removed the *secret_key_base*.
```

On logging into the Rails 4 app, a new cookie named **_custom_session** was created. The rails 2 app was also able to access the same cookie. This implied that the cookie was shared. However the user was not logged into the rails 2 app. Accessing the rails 2 app rewrote the shared cookie thus logging out the rails 4 user.

I also tried setting the domain manually, but that didn't help either:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_custom_session', domain: '.rails.local'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If they are running in the same domain have a look at [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails/10403338#10403338). Or have a look at [This Article](http://kabisa.nl/share-sessions-between-rails-2-and-rails-3-applications/) as it walks you through step by step for Rails 2 to Rails 3 so I would assume you could make it work for 4.

Comment: Thanks, but none of those solutions worked.

Comment: I was able to share the sessions between my 2 apps (Same as @Alex, Rails 2.3 and Rails 4.2) but through Redis (using the redis-sessions-store gem). Unfortunately, while it is working fine regarding the login, the flash messages aren't working (for now).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving the session from the cookie store to storing it in the DB using [activerecord-session_store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store)?

From:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_rails_session_#{Rails.env}", domain: :all
```

To something like:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => 'your_session_key_name'
```