# Rails session_store for multiple domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a basic subdomain set which is:

```
lvh.me:3000i
api.lvh.me:3000

mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
api.mydomain.com
```

Specifically the `api` domain needs to be on redis session store. So I am attempting to setup my session store, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_domain', domain: "mydomain.com"

Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store, key: '_my_dmoain', domain: "api.mydomain.com", servers: {
    host: REDIS_CONFIG["host"],
    port: REDIS_CONFIG["port"],
    db: REDIS_CONFIG["db"],
    password: REDIS_CONFIG["password"],
  }
```

How do I setup my session_store.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `tld_length` switch:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_domain', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

Info here: [Share session (cookies) between subdomains in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails/15009883#15009883)