# Devise: Sharing sessions (user state) across subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

I have my project set up using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2, and Devise 3.5.

I have an app with multiple sudomains and I would like a user's state (logged in/out) to be shared across those subdomains.

I have set my session store up like this:

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_app_name_session', :domain => '.name.app', :tld_length => 2
```

However this does not seem to be doing anything as when I inspect the session in Chrome, it is called the `_app_session`, which is the incorrect session name so this makes me think that rails is ignoring these settings.

How can I setup Devise to work using sessions that will work with all of the different sub domains?

Thanks

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Yes I didn't want to sound ignorant but you'd be surprised at the people who'd ask that question *without* restarting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the following for our subdomains:

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_[[name]]_session', domain: :all # tld_length info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails/15009883#15009883
```

You should try setting `domain: :all` and maybe removing `tld_length` from the hash

Comment: Thanks, so I got it to work by keeping the domain to '.name.app' but removing the tld_length from it.

Comment: @JasonSilberman Did you manage to share sessions between different apps under the same domain, using the same User table? I want to do the same with Devise. Any thoughts?