# Rails: Sharing Devise Sessions across multiple sub domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I have a rails app using devise to manage sessions. I want users who login to myapp.com to be able to view beta.myapp.com without having to re-login.

I followed the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails/10403338#10403338) post. Basically adding to config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

Cleared my cookies. But it's not working. The app sessions still seem to be completely separate, requiring me to login and logout of both individually.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You did it in both the apps?

Comment: yes it's in both apps

Comment: Ah, I needed to set secret_key_base to the same in both apps..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the changes in both the apps.

Change the session store in both the rails app, and their devise secret keys should be same as well.