# rails subdomain on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost, subdomain

I would like to test subdomains on localhost. I have following instructions: Before starting the server to run the application, the host should be configured so that the application can support subdomains for multiple users. To do that, go to your hosts file by typing `sudo nano /etc/hosts` in your terminal, then add subdomains at the end of the file as below:

```
127.0.0.1 admin.daycare.no
127.0.0.1 daycare.no
127.0.0.1 worker.daycare.no
127.0.0.1 manager.daycare.no
127.0.0.1 parent.daycare.no
```

I followed the above instructions. The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: `http://daycare.no:3000/`

```
Unable to determine IP address from hostname daycare.no
The DNS server returned: Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. 
Check if the address is correct.
```

How can I solve this, please?

Comment: Who added the Close flag? See me after class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After saving `/etc/hosts` file, run your rails app like this

```
rails s -p 3000 -b daycare.no
```

In a browser

```
 http://daycare.no:3000
```

Personally, I use `lvh.me:3000` just running

```
rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me
```

no need to touch `/etc/hosts` file.

By default, you can't browse the link `lvh.me:3000` without internet connection, solution is to add `127.0.0.1  lvh.me` into host file.

```
# /etc/hosts file
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   lvh.me #make sure lvh.me is after localhost otherwise will not work
```

But, Its little annoying to run this each time when restarting a server.

**Set your custom command:**

```
sudo nano .bash_profile
# OR
sudo nano .bashrc
# OR
sudo nano .profile
```

**And ADD these lines to there:**

```
alias lvh='rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me'
alias lvh_production='RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me' #production
```

Do not forget restart your terminal tab, close and open new tab OR run this command on the same tab `. ~/.bash_profile` depends what you have used on top.

---

Alternate solution is POW ([LINK](http://pow.cx/)) server can give you custom domain smth like `daycare.dev`.

Comment: Reason being that the /etc/hosts file only maps ip addresses, not ports. So the `:3000` is required.

Comment: why can't we use rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0

Comment: @DineshSaini Then, how u ll access to subdomain ? your server will run anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I use `www.vcap.me:3000`

There is no need to do extra configuration **before rails 6**.

**with rails 6**, you need to add `www.vcap.me` to environment configuration:

```
config.hosts << 'www.vcap.me'
```

You can use it like this:

```
www.vcap.me:3000
subdomain1.vcap.me:3000
subdomain2.vcap.me:3000
..
```

Comment: To allow requests to `subdomain.vcap.me`, you also need to add like so `config.hosts << "app.vcap.me"` in your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I using rails 6. You need to just follow 3 steps only and you can access your rails server with your defined URL without mentioning the port number.

1. Edit your hosts file. (as you have done already).

   ```
   nano /etc/hosts
   ```

add your URLs.

```
   127.0.0.1 admin.daycare.no
   127.0.0.1 daycare.no
   127.0.0.1 worker.daycare.no
   127.0.0.1 manager.daycare.no
   127.0.0.1 parent.daycare.no
```

2. Add all URLs to the environment configuration

   ```
   config.hosts << 'admin.daycare.no'
   config.hosts << 'daycare.no'
   config.hosts << 'worker.daycare.no'
   config.hosts << 'manager.daycare.no'
   config.hosts << 'parent.daycare.no'
   ```
3. Now just run

   ```
    rvmsudo rails s -p80
   ```

Open your url `http://admin.daycare.no` on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Editing your hosts file is an extremely messy way of doing this sort of thing. The problem here is some software doesn't read that file and goes directly to DNS to do resolving.

A service like [xip.io](http://xip.io) can help. You can use addresses like:

```
http://test.127.0.0.1.xip.io/
```

That will always resolve to 127.0.0.1.

There's also things like [Puma dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev) which come with their own resolver for the `.test` domain so `site.test` works locally without having to edit any files.

The advantage of both systems is you can add on arbitrary bits and it still works: subdomain.test.test and subdomain.127.0.0.1.xip.io also resolves the same way.