# Pow port proxying doesn't work with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, ruby-on-rails-5, rack-pow

I'm have a Rails 5 app running with Foreman and I'm trying to use Pow's port proxying to reach it. When I try to access my app at `myapp.dev` I get the following error:

> Proxy Error
>
> Couldn't proxy request to localhost:4000.
>
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

I confirmed that the problem is specific to Rails 5 by generating a fresh app that runs Rails 4 and an app that runs Rails 5. Port proxying works with the Rails 4 app but not with the Rails 5 app.

To be more specific about the version, I'm using Rails 5.0.0.rc1.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Rails or with my Pow configuration and would appreciate some insight.

Comment: just dnt use pow, it kinda slows. For subdomains there cool ez option -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521114/unable-to-determine-ip-address-from-host-name/36522401#36522401 . just using `lvh.me:3000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 5 with Puma no longer listens by default on `0.0.0.0`.

So starting your `rails server` with the option `-b 0.0.0.0` should allow Pow to reach it.

Too bad Pow does not seems to be maintain anymore.

Edit:

For those who don't want to deal with a command option, you can trick the server options [by modifying the config/boot.rb file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33249657/1683461).

Comment: That works but it requires me to make a change to my Procfile which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Then you should check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33249657/1683461).

Comment: You should check out [puma-dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev) if it fits your use case