# Ruby on Rails - Running rails server on a public IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

Is it possible to perform a

```
rails server -b my.public.ip.address -p 8000
```

running this code obviously doesn't work. So I am wondering if there is a way to around this?

Comment: Do you want to run this in development env? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521114/unable-to-determine-ip-address-from-host-name/36522401#36522401

Answer (score 13):

You can use `rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000`, and review the following things:

- You use the port 8000 in your browser, Example `http://<your-ip>:8000`
- You or you ISP don't have a firewall.

Comment: But that doesn't that work only locally?

Comment: You will need to set up port-forwarding on your router or use some sort of tunnelling service. See [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462317/boot-up-rails-app-make-request-to-app-from-outside-local-network#comment66245464_39462317).