# Custom domain in rails is not working for app.test.com:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

My company has a rails 5.2.4 application, after starting the development server by

```
rails s
```

The server is running on `localhost:3000`.
But a company is using `app.test.com:3000` domain in order to access the application...

Comment: What you see if you access app.test.com:3000 ? I kinda do not get, where is the problem. Or can you access only localhost:3000? Do you use dnsmasq ? We need more info i am affraid ...

Comment: Port 3000 is not the normal port for HTTP (80) or HTTPS (443) and you need to setup your webserver to actually allow access over that port or run rails on one of those ports.

Comment: You can also use a tunnel like NGrok.

Comment: @max thanks its working now after following "7urkm3n" answer helped me in getting the work done.

Comment: @mArtinko5MB thanks its working now after following "7urkm3n" answer helped me in getting the work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use: `lvh.me`, more about [subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521114/rails-subdomain-on-localhost/36522401#36522401)

Run  `rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me`

Visit `app.lvh.me:3000`

Comment: thanks this worked, i followed the article you have given and it solved the problem. I just need to add the domain in /etc/hosts file and it started working with app.test.com:3000.