# Can't access Rails app running on subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, dns, darwin

URL http://app.cg-dev.localhost:3000 works fine on Google Chrome. And only on it. It doesn't load on Firefox, Safari, you name it.

```
wbednarski@MP ~$ nc -vz app.cg-dev.localhost 3000
nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
wbednarski@MP ~$ telnet app.cg-dev.localhost 3000
app.cg-dev.localhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I guess that is some DNS issue or something specific to Rails set up or Google Chrome has treat `localhost` differently? Not sure how to debug it.

Rails 5.2, all browsers newest version on macOS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521114/rails-subdomain-on-localhost/36522401#36522401

Comment: `rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me` and use -> http://app.cg-dev.lvh.me:3000