# Rails redirecting to a subdomain with a notice message

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, subdomain

I am redirecting the user to a subdomain of the application based on the parameter

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html {  redirect_to home_url(subdomain: params[:company]), notice: "Couldn't able to process your request, please try after some time" }
end
```

with a notice message, and the html page to which i am redirecting the user looks like

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alerts alerts-info bodyLeftPadd" %>
<% end %>
```

for displaying the flash message.

But the problem here is the notice message is not displayed.

Is the use of subdomain causing this problem, because if remove the subdomain and if i redirect  to the url within the same subdomain i could see the flash message being displayed.

```
 respond_to do |format|
          format.html {  redirect_to home_url, notice: "Couldn't able to process your request, please try after some time" }
 end
```

Comment: what if you try `flash: { notice: "Couldn't able to process your request, please try after some time" }`

Comment: @Andrey Deineko Yes i have tried that too, but the message is not displayed.

Comment: try to comment out your part with `flash.each...` - see if default behaviour works. Your code looks OK

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thanks for your response., i have also tried the same but i couldn't get the message being displayed.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko i have made some edit can you look over into that

Comment: can't help you out here unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash messages are stored in your session, which is tied to a cookie. (If you're using `cookie_store` all session data is kept in the cookie, or if you're using `active_record_session` you have a session cookie which is tied to data in your database).

The problem is that cookies won't follow you across subdomains unless you've configured them to.  See [Share session (cookies) between subdomains in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails)

It sounds like the critical part is to include `domain: '.yourdomain.com'` in the line where you configure your session store. From [Action Controller Overview: Sessions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session):

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session', domain: ".example.com"
```