# Are browser sessions unique for each subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

Say I'm running a multi-tenant application that gives each organization its own portal via a subdomain.

Example -

- `orgA.application.com`
- `orgB.application.com`
- etc...

Each subdomain reads from a different schema/tenant in my PSQL db, but is otherwise the same application.

In my `ApplicationController` I set the `current_user` as -

```
def current_user
  if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

There are few admin/superusers such as myself that have a user account on each subdomain. If I log into `orgA` with my user (`id = 22`), then my `session` gets set as `user_id: 22`.

Now say I want to switch over to `orgB`, where my user id is `44`. If I log into `orgB` after having set my session in `orgA`, is there any chance I could accidentally log myself in as the user who is `22` on `orgB`?

More fundamentally, I'm trying to understand how a browser cookie session is set. From my understanding, it's a hash of variables that are encrypted and cached in the client's browser. Is that set per subdomain? Or do all subdomains of a particular site share the same cache/session cookie?

More importantly, how do I prevent cross pollination of sessions like in the example above? Is my `current_user` method too basic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fundamentally asking about cookies here, to which the answer is relatively simple: cookies are *not* shared across subdomains unless you explicitly request it.

When you send the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header to create a cookie in the user's browser, you can choose whether or not to include a `domain` configuration option. That option controls which domain the cookie saves under and will be served to.

By default, if you send `Set-Cookie` with no `domain` option, the cookie will be set *for the current hostname*, which includes subdomains. That is, a cookie set on `siteA.example.com` will not be accessible to `siteB.example.com`.

If you send a `domain` option of `example.com` when you create your cookie on `siteA.example.com`, then the cookie will be accessible on both `example.com` and `*.example.com`, so all your sites will be able to access it.

For your situation, then, you should send the `Set-Cookie` header with *no* `domain` option. That's the default in most setups, [including Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails) so it's unlikely you need to do anything.

Comment: Sounds like I'm in the clear leaving it with the default. Perfect and clear explanation - thank you!