# Multiple apps for different sub domains or just one big app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, subdomain, aws-sdk

When it comes to sub domains in AWS (payments.x.com and forums.x.com) do I upload completely different rails apps for the payments and the forums?

If so how do I make sure that the logged in user is carried over from one to the other when using Postgres?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share session (cookies) between subdomains in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails)

Comment: The rest is pretty much just opinion based on your specific requirements...

Comment: @BradWerth will my postgres just automatically work for the subdomain too?