# How to do omniauth on wildcard subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm have omniauth working in my Rails app on the top level domain.

Now I want to do it on any given subdomain (users each get their own subdomain assigned dynamically).

- I can't find a way to dynamically change the callback url on the fly with omniauth
- Leaving it as is, in the callback I can see the referrer and know which subdomain they came from, and log them in, but when I then redirect them to their subdomain they are logged out because the session was on the top level domain.

I'm using the omniauth-facebook gem if that matters: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Omniauth let's you change this dynamically, but you can share the session between all subdomains, and continue to use the redirection approach. Just change your `session_store` to include `domain` (and `tld_length` if you need it - more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009883/7671538))

```
Rails.application.config.session_store ... , domain: :all
```