# Rails not retaining session on second call when deployed to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have created a Rails app that I'm using as api app (with an angular front end).  When I try to create a session on `SessionsController#create`, I am setting `session[:user_id]` and returning a user object.  My front end app is successfully getting this object and redirecting the browser to #/dashboard.  `DashboardComponent` has a guard that calls my `SessionsController#logged_in` which checks for a session in my rails app.  When I'm running locally, this works with no issues.  However, when deployed to Heroku, `session[:user_id]` is empty.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I know it's not a CORS or a CSRF issue because my client app gets the user object (I am logging it to the console).

Here is my `initializers/session_store.rb`

```
if Rails.env == "production"
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp", domain: "api-app.herokuapp.com"
else
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp"
end
```

And just for fun, here's my `initializers/cors.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "http://localhost:4200", "https://angular-app.herokuapp.com"
    resource "*", 
      headers: :any, 
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head], 
      credentials: true
  end
end
```

`SessionsController.rb`

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    include CurrentUserConcern
  
    def create
      user = User
              .find_by(email: params["email"])
              .try(:authenticate, params["password"])
  
      if user
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        render json: user, status: :created
      else
        head :unauthorized
      end
    end
  
    def logged_in
      if @current_user
        render json: @current_user, status: :ok
      else
        head :no_content
      end
    end
  
    def logout
      reset_session
      head :no_content
    end
  end
```

`current_user_concern.rb`

```
module CurrentUserConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_current_user, only: [:logged_in]
  end

  def set_current_user
    puts session[:user_id]
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

I can provide any other code that might help

Comment: The cookie isn't being shared between the api domain (api-app.herokuapp.com) and the angular domain (angular-app.herokuapp.com). It will always look like a new session to the api app. Need to update your  Rails.application.config.session_store to work across subdomains. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails for some hints, likely need to set the tld_length.

Comment: I modified the production config on `session_store.rb` to this: `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp", domain: :all, tld_length: 2` but this did not resolve my issue.

Comment: A cookie isn't added.  I also tried adding my client app domain to the session_store, like this: `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp", domain: "thawing-river-95379.herokuapp.com", tld_length: 2`, but it also had no effect

Comment: What does your angular code look like to call the api login?  Guessing it does not do anything with the cookie, betting you need to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with a custom domain name.  i set my angular app to use [www.kroe761.com](http://www.kroe761.com) and my api to use api.kroe761.com.  i then set my session_store to this:
`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_myapp", domain: :all, tld_length: 2`

So, clearly the issue had something to do with the domains of the client and api being different.  I don't know how to configure everything under that scenario (if you do, please add an answer for my edification), but for now the issue is resolved.