# Can't login to Rails application in Brave Browser (private mode) due to duplicate session cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I noticed that I have always had issues when it came to logging into my Rails app when using the Brave Browser in private model. When I referred to [this comment](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/2734#issuecomment-49593864), this helped me fix the issue in development I believe (or at least temporarily), but after pushing this change to production, I'm running into the same issue.

When I login, I see the following in the Rails console:

```
I, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.736777 #228]  INFO -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d] Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 71.199.129.20 at 2020-12-24 19:43:48 +0000
I, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.737556 #228]  INFO -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d] Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.737613 #228]  INFO -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"a94x1G4PTP/UUs571hnYPenK0+UN6vK3+a+0WGY1GlNkXDLO42Xvpq3ph9cXm+yvdyxNBz/Clz9dDjPLk1Ii3g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"myuser@domain.io", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "button"=>""}
W, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.746737 #228]  WARN -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d] Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
D, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.748787 #228] DEBUG -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d]   User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "myuser@domain.io"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.860181 #228] DEBUG -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d]    (1.5ms)  BEGIN
...
D, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.881760 #228] DEBUG -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d]    (1.9ms)  SELECT MAX("audits"."version") FROM "audits" WHERE "audits"."auditable_id" = $1 AND "audits"."auditable_type" = $2  [["auditable_id", 1], ["auditable_type", "User"]]
D, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.883564 #228] DEBUG -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d]   Audited::Audit Create (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "audits" ("auditable_id", "auditable_type", "user_id", "user_type", "action", "audited_changes", "version", "remote_address", "request_uuid", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["auditab$
e_id", 1], ["auditable_type", "User"], ["user_id", 1], ["user_type", "User"], ["action", "update"], ["audited_changes", "---\nauthy_code:\n- 8c3249\n- bbd5cb\n"], ["version", 1702], ["remote_address", "71.199.129.20"], ["request_uuid", "2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d"], ["created_at", "2020-12-24 19:43:48.879538"]]                                          D, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.885321 #228] DEBUG -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d]   Consultant Update (1.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1, "authy_code" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", "2020-12-24 19:43:48.878303"], ["authy_code", "bbd5cb"], ["id", 1]]
D, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.887646 #228] DEBUG -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d]    (1.9ms)  COMMIT
I, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.888397 #228]  INFO -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d] Redirected to https://app.domain.io/authentication_method
I, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.888515 #228]  INFO -- : [2d546938-c52a-465f-8269-6b0a5871cc8d] Completed 302 Found in 151ms (ActiveRecord: 24.2ms)
I, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.926474 #228]  INFO -- : [3b441671-ef25-4483-8623-ae9d33820733] Started GET "/authentication_method" for 71.199.129.20 at 2020-12-24 19:43:48 +0000                                                                                                                                                                                                  I, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.927153 #228]  INFO -- : [3b441671-ef25-4483-8623-ae9d33820733] Processing by CommonController#authentication_method as HTML
I, [2020-12-24T19:43:48.935237 #228]  INFO -- : [3b441671-ef25-4483-8623-ae9d33820733] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
```

I know the issue is related to the CSRF token, but even disabling the Brave shield in private mode doesn't seem to do the trick.

When I look into Brave's cookies for the domain, I see the following:

[image]

Here's what I have in my `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: "_my_company_session_#{Rails.env}", domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

How can I fix this? I'm assuming that the issue here is that there are duplicate cookies being assigned when browsing to the app, one for the `.domain.io` domain and the other for `app.domain.io` domain.

Comment: Think you have a domain issue, it sets this cookie for one domain (.domain.io) when you are open Sign in page but then you are submitting it to a different (app.domain.io).

Comment: if using subdomain, its the issue coming from it. if planning to use the same session for entire domain itself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails/43023869#43023869

Comment: I think the only potential issue with that solution for me is that I have different CNAME records that are set up to point to the domain. So by setting a hardcoded domain, I'd have to modify this each time right?