# Authenticate in a external site using Joomla session

Tags: php, authentication, joomla

i'm new here and i really need a hand here.

I have a system running in Joomla and a External Site (PHP). There's a way to use the Joomla authentication to login the external site? I mean, the user **MUST be logged in joomla to access the external site, and not the other way.** If not logged in joomla, cant access...

I you could explain me like i'm 2 years old, would be nice, since i don't know much abou  joomla.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Just toss the session over

Comment: like i'm 2 years old ...=).

How ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: no if they don't meet certain requirements.

The Joomla site needs offer an authorization service (like [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) or [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)) and the External Site needs to connect to this API.

If both sites share the same domain, they could share cookies for validation: [sub-domain cookies, sent in a parent domain request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865345/sub-domain-cookies-sent-in-a-parent-domain-request/3865510#3865510).

Another option could be using iframes and javascript, but any of the options cannot be ELY2, there are different degrees of abstraction with each method.

Comment: I can put all at the same domain. In worpress i've found a solution, but for joomla i didn't yet

Comment: That would make the process easier, yet I don't think it makes it easy enough to be explained in full here at SO. You might need to reuse some part of Joomla at the other site.